Enforcing consistent table-cell text wrapping when final cell is "width 100%"
See the two-cell table in the demo here.
https://plnkr.co/edit/EpAX5Mo5YWetj02E
HTML:
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
        </head>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    https://example.com/one-two-three/four
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>

CSS:
td:last-child {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

The yellow, blank cell is styled to be width 100%. This provokes different text wrapping in Firefox

than in Chrome or Safari...

Are both of these behaviours correct? Is there a way to make Firefox behave like Chrome?
I have tried two solutions which fix this specific example but are no good to me in practice. Firstly, adding a min-width to the TD containing the text (but in the real world I have some columns of containing short strings where a minimum width looks bad). Secondly I have tried replacing the yellow TD with a DIV outside the table (but in the real world the rows of the table are zebra striped and I want the background colour of of each row to extend over the width of the window).

The different behaviours are caused by the slashes(/). By default the UA determines which character set allows line break or not.  Hence we can't say either browser is incorrect. A discussion thread suggests FF follows this standard, which does allows breaking at slash. That being said, I don't know a pure CSS way to get them behave the same though.
